# How do we go from $x^n - a^n$ to $(x-a)(x^{n-1}+ ax^{n-2} +\ldots + xa^{n-2} + a^{n-1})$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits

This is involved in the proof of the standard limit x tends to a:$\dfrac{(x^n - a^n)}{(x - a)}$. How can we prove this statement and how do we know that the second term ends at $x^0$. Is this limit defined only for positive $n$ and positive $a$?
PS: I understand how we can go from the RHS to the LHS, I want to know how to go from the LHS to the RHS.
Thank you

Comment: We have $$(x-a) \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}x^{k}a^{(n-1) -k}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}x^{k+1}a^{(n-1)-k}-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}x^{k}a^{n-k}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}x^{k}a^{n-k}-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}x^{k}a^{n-k}=x^n-a^n$$

Comment: Hint: $x^{n-1}+ax^{n-2}+a^2x^{n-3}+\cdots+a^{n-1}$ is a geometric series with common ratio $\frac ax$.

Comment: You haven't expressed the limit you are interested in (as $x\to a$ I think): but what you have is a simple polynomial identity, which can be proved in various ways. One way is simply to multiply out and see that most of the terms cancel.

Answer (score 1):

Why should you “go from the LHS to the RHS”? In order to compute the derivative at $a$ of $f(x)=x^n$ you *don't* need the full identity.

What you need is polynomial division and induction.

Set $g_n(x)=x^n-a^n$. Then you know that
$$
g_n(x)=(x-a)q_n(x)
$$
where $q_n$ is a polynomial of degree $n-1$ (we assume that $n\ge1$). For $n=1$ we have $q_1(x)=1$; for $n=2$ we have $q_2(x)=x+a$; for $n=3$ we have $q_3(x)=x^2+ax+a^2$ and we can *conjecture* that
$$
q_n(a)=na^{n-1}
$$
Is this right? Let's see
\begin{align}
g_{n+1}(x)
&=x^{n+1}-a^{n+1}=x^{n+1}-ax^n+ax^n-a^{n+1} \\
&=x^n(x-a)+a(x^n-a^n)\\
&=x^n(x-a)+a(x-a)q_n(x)\\
&=(x-a)(x^n+aq_n(x)
\end{align}
and by uniqueness of the quotient we get
$$
q_{n+1}(x)=x^n+aq_n(x)
$$
Therefore
$$
q_{n+1}(a)=a^n+a\cdot na^{n-1}=(n+1)a^n
$$
as we wanted to prove.

You don't get away from doing a conjecture in either case: the identity
$$
x^n-a^n=(x-a)(x^{n-1}+ax^{n-2}+\dots+a^{n-2}x+a^{n-1})
$$
*is* a conjecture to be proved by induction. The proof is almost self-evident, but it's necessary and it isn't pedantry.

Answer (score -1):

Most people would be satisfied to see this from algebraic manipulation, but if you need to prove it you can do so easily with induction, in the following manner:
$$
(x-a)(x+a)=x^2-ax+ax-a^2=x^2-a^2
$$
Extending,
$$
\begin{align}
(x-a)(x^2+ax+a^2)
&=x^3-ax^2+(x-a)(ax+a^2)\\
&=x^3-ax^2+ax^2-a^3\\
&=x^3-a^3
\end{align}
$$

and so on.

> how do we know that the second term ends at $x^0$?

If we set $x=a$ then $x-a=a-a$ is zero and $x^n-a^n=a^n-a^n$ is zero, so we know that $x-a$ is a factor of $x^n-a^n$, so there are no terms involving reciprocals of $x-a$ after the division.

> Is this limit defined only for positive $n$ and positive $a$?

This relation is only true for positive integer $n\geq 2$, but $a$ may take any value.

Comment: I understand this. I wanted to know if we could go from the LHS TO the RHS, like, manipulating the term on the LHS to get the one on the right.

Comment: Look up "polynomial division". For example [Polynomial long division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division) at Wikipedia.

Comment: Thank you for this link, i remember this now.